# How to revamp my hard-drive and then do a dual-boot with Windows XP and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Ubuntu currently installed?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows, windows-xp

I had Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a secondhand PC I bought sometime back and I have to say it's better than Windows any day. However, I now need both Windows and Ubuntu on my PC. I've already backed up my data and burned a Windows XP SP3 installation CD.

One of my biggest problems is that my hard drive, which is about 320 GB SATA, has about 4-5 partitions and 2 unallocated ones of about 5 GB and 7 MB. See the screenshot of GParted:

[image: Gparted]

I really don't know much about computers in details, so I want everything to go smoothly.
Here's what I'm going for:

1. Undoing all partitions into one.
2. Installing Windows XP
3. Create a second partition
4. Install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

How to undo partitions? Should I go in for a complete format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're on the right track. Installing Windows before Ubuntu works best.

One way to format the drive is to use a Linux distro with GParted on it that runs from a CD. This way the drive is not mounted. I don't think you can safely format a mounted root partition.

What you want to do in GParted is delete all partitions then apply. That should be fine. Windows should be able to then format the drive during the Windows installation process. Have Windows only create a partition for itself, leaving space for Ubuntu.

If you have issues, you could drop to the Windows console during the installation process and run `fixboot` and `fixmbr`. When you install Ubuntu, GRUB will take over the Master Boot Record process.

You're on the right track.